# How to generated signed APKs in Travis without checking the keystore in the repository?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am building an Android application in Travis, from where I send it to Crashlytics Beta to distribute it.

Now, I want this APK signed with my release keys. But I do not want to upload the keystore file to the repository.

Is there a way to pass this file to Travis without checking it into the code repository?